# Using cv::Mat with multi-dimensional FFTW3

Tags: c++, opencv, fftw

Is there anyway how to use `fftw_plan fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(int n0, int n1,double *in, fftw_complex *out, unsigned flags)` function from FFTW3 with input as a data from cv::Mat object? My currently working code looks like this:

```
data_in =  fftwf_alloc_real(width * height);
fft = fftwf_alloc_complex((width/2+1) * height);

plan_f=fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_2d( height , width , data_in, fft ,  FFTW_MEASURE );
// Prepare input data
for(int i = 0,k=0; i < height; ++i) {
    const float* row = input.ptr<float>(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        data_in[k]=(float)row[j];
        k++;
    }
}

// Exectue fft
fftwf_execute( plan_f );
```

where **data_in** is array type `float*` and **input** is `cv::Mat`. I would like to get rid off the for cycles copying the data to **data_in** and just use the already allocated data from **input**.

Comment: you want to copy data from `cv::Mat` to `float[]`, right?

Comment: I would like to completely avoid copying the data from the `cv::Mat` and use them as `float*` for the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your snippet correctly, you want to copy data from `cv::Mat` to a float array. Assuming your `cv::Mat` is of type `CV_32F` (floats), instead of copying every element separately, you can just copy the whole block with [`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy):

```
std::memcpy(data_in, input.data, input.total() * sizeof(float));
```

or you could skip the copying altogether and just use `(float*)input.data`

Comment: I tried to use `(float*)input.data` before posting here but unfortunately this does not work. It returns only zeros after executing the plan. I wonder if it has something to do with cv::Mat using steps to access data?

Comment: Ok I found the problem. It seems that FFTW deletes data in input array if it is initialized before the creation of the plan. It seems that `FFTW_ESTIMATE` flag helps to solve this issue. So now I can use `(float*)input.data`. Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: @VítKarafiát so what is the solution you ended up with to solve the issue?

Comment: @Ja_cpp I am using `plan_f=fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_2d( height , width , (float*)input.data, fft ,  FFTW_ESTIMATE );` now.